# Difference in sent bytes and connect time for Java and HTTP Client 4 implemenation in JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I am using Jmeter for webservice -Restful testing.

I am getting the following error:

> Software caused connection abort: socket write error

for post method, where i am sending the JSON request of size 1MB and used HTTPclient4 implementation.

Later I tried to use the Java implementation, there I am getting successful response but the sent bytes count is 0 for Java and where for HTTPclient4 it is very high.

**Sampler Result:**

#### HTTPclient4

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2019-02-19 10:00:57 EST
Load time: 770
Connect Time: 295
Latency: 770
Size in bytes: 151
Sent bytes:1112854
Headers size in bytes: 151
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): 
Response code: 200
Response message: OK


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

**Sampler Result:**

#### JAVA implementation:

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2019-02-19 10:06:08 EST
Load time: 217
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 217
Size in bytes: 151
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 151
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): 
Response code: 200
Response message: OK


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

How the JAVA implementation works and why the size in bytes is 0 for JAVA implementation in jmeter.

pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java implementation does not compute sent bytes which is why you get 0:

- https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/src/protocol/http/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPJavaImpl.java

Only HTTPClient 4 does:

- https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/src/protocol/http/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPHC4Impl.java#L630

Comment: Thanks for sharing it.